# Elastic Search: Unable to query data from a remote machine on 9200 port

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to access query:

```
POST myindex/_count
```

using URL:

```
http://ip.ip.ip.ip:9200/myindex/_count
```

But it says 'The web page is not available'

My Analysis so far and isolations

1. I can access Kibana from remote machine as http://ip.ip.ip.ip:5601 but not port 9200.
2. So, I think, I need to change state of port 9200 such that it is too in listening mode as port 5601.
3. I also doubt if this is possible, as we would basically be requesting a write operation over web.
4. The examples i have seen so far, have a service deployed on the same machine which pushes data on that machine. I want to be able to push data from different machine over web requests.

Update: This works when I put the hostname instead of IP.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall?

Comment: Are you sure the IP address you're using is not a private IP address (e.g. 10.x.y.z)?

Comment: Yeah, it is a private ip address. 10.x.x.x

Comment: And you're trying from your local workstation or directly on that remote host?

Comment: I am trying from my local workstation

Comment: Ok, it's normal then, as you cannot access private IP addresses from the outside world. How do you log into that box?

Comment: My local workstation is also in the same network and has ip on the range 10.x.x.x . And  the system has a domain user added as admin. Using that account